# bash built-in functions for management of date time

Tags: bash, datetime

I have data that looks like this:

```
2020/09/20 15:44:26.609
2020/09/20 15:44:26.610
2020/09/20 15:44:26.615
2020/09/20 15:44:26.616
2020/09/20 15:44:27.616
```

There are thousands of entries over many days.

I would like to calculate differences of the various times to calculate moving averages etc. Is there a way to calculate this directly in bash?

Comment: For complex data manipulation, a higher level language (e.g. python) that has robust support for time-based calculations is going to make these sorts of tasks much easier. Or just load your data into Excel.

Comment: Converting your timestamps to ISO-8601 formats and loading your data into a sqlite (Or other) database is another approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bash is a shell. A shell is a tool to create/destroy files and processes and sequence calls to tools. The tool that the guys who invented the Unix shell also invented for the shell to call to manipulate text is `awk`.

With GNU awk for `mktime()` and `gensub()`:

```
$ awk -F'.' '{print $0, "->", mktime(gensub("[/:]"," ","g",$1))*1000 + $2}' file
2020/09/20 15:44:26.609 -> 1600634666609
2020/09/20 15:44:26.610 -> 1600634666610
2020/09/20 15:44:26.615 -> 1600634666615
2020/09/20 15:44:26.616 -> 1600634666616
2020/09/20 15:44:27.616 -> 1600634667616
```

If that's not all you need the update your question to provide more truly representative sample input, the associated expected output, and a clearer statement of your requirements.

Comment: Thank You! I guess I look at bash or any of the shells as a complete environment of interactive tools. That when used effectively as you demonstrated  can solve most basic processing needs w/o the need to move to a programming language..

Comment: You're confusing bash with Unix. Bash (or any other shell) is just one of the set of tools in a Unix environment and it's job is to sequence the calls to the other tools as well as manipulate files and processes. When you ask for a "bash solution" or to "calculate this directly in bash" some people will interpret that as meaning you want a solution using only bash builtins (constructs that are part of the bash language) and not any of the other Unix tools you can call from bash. Don't confuse bash built-ins with mandatory Unix tools.